# String to Datetime C#

Tags: string, c#-4.0

String="880814" now i want to display this string as 88/08/14 by either means

- either by parsing it into Datetime
- or simply by inserting "/" in b/w
  How????

Comment: Parsing it will not display it.

Comment: I would recommend you look into some of the copious [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx) on date string parsing.

Or one of the many "suggested questions" that came up when you wrote your subject.

Comment: one easy possible solution is to split that string into 3 substring and then concatinate them with '/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to insert the `/` to the string if you simply want to output a string with them:

```
"880814".Insert(4, "/").Insert(2, "/")
```

I don't see the point of parsing the string into a `DateTime` just to output it again to a string, unless you need to validate the string as a valid date and possibly make sure that you can change the formatting easily.

Comment: I'd view both of the "unless" points as simply good practice, personally. I'd have to have strong reasons to go with something which completely ignores the expected meaning of the data.

Comment: @JonSkeet - It's a fair point. In my opinion it really depends on what exactly is done with this data. Keeping it semantically right is important, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming this should be interpreted as 2-digit-year month day...

I would suggest you parse it as a `DateTime` and then convert it to a custom format. For example, using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
DateTime date;
// null means "current culture" - may or may not be appropriate
// Ditto the AssumeLocal value...
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "yyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
                           out date))
{
    // Note this will use the date separator of the current culture
    string formatted = date.ToString("yy/MM/dd");
    // Use formatted
}
else
{
    // Couldn't be parsed - handle appropriately.
}
```

I *wouldn't* just insert the slashes manually, as otherwise you won't catch invalid data as early as you can by parsing/reformatting. The above code also lends itself better to situations where *either* your input format *or* your output format changes - for example, if you wanted to change to "dd-MM-yyyy" format, doing that via string manipulation changes significantly, but by parsing and reformatting, it's just a very minor change which would be obvious in code review.

Comment: Looks like the OP simply wants to _output_ the string with `/` added. I don't think parsing is needed.

Comment: @Oded: Yup, I was editing - including why I wouldn't just put the slashes in.

Comment: @JonSkeet I just happen to have a related date parse problem this morning that this solved perfectly. I was unaware of DateTime.TryParseExact. Thank you so much.